# Rewrite an object as an array?

Tags: php, arrays, object

I'm using curl to fetch some data from a website. After I process it I manage to get it to this state:

```
Array ( 
[GraphicRiver] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object 
    ( 
        [id] => 698515 
        [item] => Alien Icons Set 
        [url] => http://graphicriver.net/item/alien-icons-set/698515 
        [user] => chaoscod3r 
        [thumbnail] => http://2.s3.envato.com/files/23574322/Thumb.jpg 
        [sales] => 5 
        [rating] => 0 
        [cost] => 5.00 
        [uploaded_on] => Mon Oct 24 17:16:20 +1100 2011 
        [tags] => alien icons, clean icons, easy editing, icons pack, minimalist icons pack, resizable, simple icons, vector icons, vector shapes 
        [category] => icons/miscellaneous 
        [live_preview_url] => http://3.s3.envato.com/files/23574321/Preview.jpg 
    )
)

)
```

but what I want to have instead of that stdClass Object is Array, so how do I rewrite this kind of array to make that object and array ?

This is the method I'm using to get what's above:

```
public function all_items_by_site($user_name) {

  $items_by_marketplace = $this->user_items_by_site($user_name);

  $marketplaces = array();

  $items = array();

  foreach ($items_by_marketplace as $key) {
     $marketplaces[] = array(
        'Marketplace'  => $key->site,
        'Items'        => $key->items
     );
  }

  foreach ($marketplaces as $key) {
     $items[$key['Marketplace']] = $this->new_files_from_user($user_name, $key['Marketplace']);
  }

  return $items;

}
```

I'm using this api wrapper as base api wrapper for what I want to develop: https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Envato-Marketplace-API-Wrapper-in-PHP .

Comment: On a side note, envato have an API for their marketplace websites, it might make your work a little easier: http://marketplace.envato.com/api/documentation

Comment: Yes, I'm using that already, but it returns data as objects. And I need it as arrays, it's easier for me to use it with the database.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can easily cast `stdClass` objects to an array:

```
$array = (array)$object;
```

In your concrete case that would be:

```
foreach ($array['GraphicRiver'] as &$item) {
    $item = (array)$item;
}
unset($item);
```

Comment: I shall try it and see what I get :)

Comment: The thing is that I don't have the array just like that, that in fact is only one of the keys, ( I'm talking about "GraphicRiver" ), because there are other keys like "CodeCanyon" and so on each one having the same structure. So I  would need to apply this to all of the keys. I've updated my question with some code example.

Answer (score 1):

The most easy way to do that (although it's not the really semantic way) is to use combination of `json_encode` and `json_decode` like this:

```
$array = json_decode(json_encode($orig), true);
```

It's very easy but I would not recomment it for big arrays.
Another way is to loop through your array and apply type casting with `(array)`:

```
$array = array_map(function($el) {
    return (array)$el;
}, $orig);
```

Comment: It is a big array, with a lot of data.

Comment: The method with json works without problems, but seems like the second one doesn't. Thanks for the solution. I hope it won't cause problems for bigger arrays than the one I have for now.